# Jackson and JSON when the type of a value changes

Tags: java, json, jackson

Using Java 8 and Jackson, I am trying to parse JSON from here:

[REST Endpoint](http://legacy.cafebonappetit.com/api/2/menus?cafe=401&date=2016-03-01,2016-03-02)

The problem is, there is a single value that sometimes is an empty array and sometimes is a HashMap. I pasted two excerpts below, check out cor_icon in each:

```
"2630775": {
  "id": "2630775",
  "label": "breakfast grill",
  "description": "breakfast sandwiches, turkey sausage and bacon, home fries, pork sausage and bacon, omelets made to order with whole eggs, egg whites, eggbeaters and assorted fillings",
  "zero_entree": "0",
  "cor_icon": {
    "18": "humane"
  },
```

Or:

```
    "4779080": {
  "id": "4779080",
  "label": "sweet chili vegan soup\nchicken egg drop soup",
  "description": "",
  "zero_entree": "0",
  "cor_icon": {
    "1": "vegetarian",
    "4": "vegan"
  },
```

As opposed to:

```
"2630777": {
  "id": "2630777",
  "label": "morning pastries",
  "description": "assorted danish, muffins, bagels, coffee cakes and tea breads",
  "zero_entree": "0",
  "cor_icon": [],
  "ordered_cor_icon": [],
```

For my Java setter:

```
@JsonSetter("cor_icon")
public void setCorIcon(HashMap ci)
{
    cor_icon = ci;
}
```

or better:

```
@JsonSetter("cor_icon")
public void setCorIcon(HashMap<String, String> ci)
{
    cor_icon = ci;
}
```

This works fine when there is data but when there is not, when I get "cor_icon":[] Jackson throws an exception saying it can not deserialize a HashMap from cor_icon. If I change cor_icon to an ArrayList then when there is data Jackson complains that it can't deserialize an ArrayList from cor_icon.

So what's the trick?

Comment: This article might be able to help you. http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify type that is valid for both JSON Arrays and JSON Objects. Two obvious choices are `java.lang.Object` and `JsonNode`: in first case, you'll get either `List` or `Map` (and need to cast); in latter case `ArrayNode` or `ObjectNode`.

Comment: I really hate doing stuff like this but it seems like the easiest approach, thanks.

Comment: @JimArcher Actually, re-reading the question: perhaps you were rather looking for `DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_ARRAY_AS_NULL_OBJECT`, which works around oddity of some langs (PHP?) serialization, where empty/missing object is serialized as empty JSON Array for some reason.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out. At this point I've done all the casting but I might re-so it...